# Javascript not working in IE8 for Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have this JavaScript for a mega menu that will not display in IE8. It works perfectly fine in all other browsers. Normally, I wouldn't care a whole lot, but our customers are older and we actually have a lot of traffic in this browser. Any tips?

Using Jquery 1.10.2

Javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery(".mega-menu-handle-1").hover(
function() {
jQuery(".mega-menu-1").addClass("display-mega");
},
function() {
jQuery(".mega-menu-1").removeClass("display-mega");
});</script>

<script>jQuery(".mega-menu-handle-2").hover(
function () {
jQuery(".mega-menu-2").addClass("display-mega");
},
function () {
jQuery(".mega-menu-2").removeClass("display-mega");
});</script>

<script>jQuery(".mega-menu-handle-4").hover(
function () {
jQuery(".mega-menu-4").addClass("display-mega");
},
function () {
jQuery(".mega-menu-4").removeClass("display-mega");
});</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mega-holder">
<div class="mega-menu mega-menu-1 mega-menu-handle-1">
<ul class="block-grid columns3 no-pad">
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h3>Shop <a class="view-all" href="/collections/air-purifiers/" title="View All Air Purifiers">View All</a></h3>
<ul class="block-grid columns2">
<li>
<h5>By Brand</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.air-purifier-brands.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h5>More Products</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.air-purifier-more-products.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<h5>By Concern</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.shop-by-concern.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h3>Learn <a class="view-all" href="/pages/air-purifiers-america-learning-center">View All</a></h3>
<h5>About Air Purifiers</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.air-purifiers-learn.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container mega-ad-space"> <a href="{{ settings.mega-menu-1-link }}"> <img src="{{'mega-menu-1-image.png' | asset_url}}" alt="" /> </a> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mega-menu mega-menu-2 mega-menu-handle-2">
<ul class="block-grid columns3 no-pad">
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h3>Shop <a class="view-all" href="/pages/air-purifier-replacement-filters">View All</a></h3>
<h5>By Brand</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.air-filter-brands.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h3>Learn <a class="view-all" href="/pages/air-purifiers-america-learning-center">View All</a></h3>
<h5>About Air Purifier Filters</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.about-air-purifier-filters.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h5>About Home HVAC Filters</h5>
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.about-home-hvac-filters.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container mega-ad-space"> <a href="{{ settings.mega-menu-2-link }}"> <img src="{{'mega-menu-2-image.png' | asset_url}}" alt="" /> </a> </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mega-menu mega-menu-4 mega-menu-handle-4 learning-center">
<ul class="block-grid columns5 no-pad">
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h5>Learn</h5>
<img src="{{ 'learning-center-1.jpg' | asset_url | image_tag }}" alt="" />
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.learning-center-learn.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h5>Compare</h5>
<img src="{{ 'learning-center-2.jpg' | asset_url | image_tag }}" alt="" />
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.learning-center-compare.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h5>Top 3 Air Purifiers</h5>
<img src="{{ 'learning-center-3.jpg' | asset_url | image_tag }}" alt="" />
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.learning-center-top-3.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container">
<h5>Articles</h5>
<img src="{{ 'learning-center-4.jpg' | asset_url | image_tag }}" alt="" />
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.learning-center-articles.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="mega-container last-mega-container">
<h5>Support</h5>
<img src="{{ 'learning-center-5.jpg' | asset_url | image_tag }}" alt="" />
<ul class="mega-list">
{% for link in linklists.learning-center-support.links %}
<li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
<div class="mega-padding">
<hr />
<a href="#" class="mega-view-all">View All</a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm working in Shopify, thus the liquid handles in there, don't mind them.

I added the conditional comment to my theme but it's still not helping.
    
      </script>

Comment: If you're only applying and removing classes via just a `hover` event, have you considered using CSS rather than javascript? For example: `.mega-menu-handle-1:hover .mega-menu-1 { attributes of display-mega here }`. It's the oldskool way of making dropdowns (used to work in IE6!)

Comment: Related to your question though - I'd state the version of jQuery that you're using. The latest jQuery, 2.x, does not work on IE8. That would explain why the code above does not work.

Comment: I'm attempting to fix something another developer did. I can definitely try that, but was just wondering if there was an easier fix in the way it is already developed that I can do instead. The 'ol CSS menu is my normal go to because it seems pretty bullet-proof. Thanks so much @AdamKewley

Comment: I added this conditional script to my theme, but the dropdown still isn't working: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Ensure that the `<script src...` tag is below the higher jQuery script in the document. If you've put that conditional above it then the newer version will overwrite your shim. To me, your javascript seems innocent enough. For other people's benefit, I'd reccomend providing the generated html rather than the (I assume) Jekyll liquid precursor, just incase site generation is to blame.